# git merge ambiguous while merging two branches

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge

When I was working on merging couple of branches, i have accidentally created a branch instead of merging,

**Example :**

I was checking the list of branches available in the `local` and `origin` by typing `git branch`. But accidentally i have executed `git branch origin/DEV66` (`origin/DEV66` is the branch i need to merge with the branch `test`).

So I have the following problem when merging the branch `test` and `origin/DEV66`

```
warning: refname 'origin/DEV_66' is ambiguous.
warning: refname 'origin/DEV_66' is ambiguous.
```

When typing `git branch` it shows the following branches

```
GRNDEV_893
heads/origin/GRNDEV_893
remotes/origin/GRNDEV_893
```

How to resolve this ambiguity and is there is any different between the branches `heads/origin/GRNDEV_893` and `remotes/origin/GRNDEV_893`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Branches in `heads/` are branches local to your repository, which you've created in this clone with `git branch` or `git checkout -b`. Branches in `remotes/` are *remote tracking branches*, which are read-only copies of branches from other clones that are updated with you run a `git fetch` or a `git pull`.

When you have branches with the same name in both, you can disambiguate by including the `heads/` or `remotes/` prefix:

```
git checkout test
git merge remotes/origin/DEV_66
```

Since you created `heads/origin/DEV_66` by mistake, you can delete it like so:

```
git branch -d heads/origin/DEV_66
```

Answer (score 0):

`git branch -rv` will show all branches including remote branches, and commit each branch is pointing to at the moment. You can further inspect each branch by  viewing log:

```
git log BRANCHNAME
```

In case some branches are identical and you would like to delete them, you can do that using

```
git branch -d BRANCHNAME
```

Comment: Can't you just do "git log BRANCHNAME"

Answer (score 0):

> How to resolve this ambiguity and is there is any different between the branches `heads/origin/GRNDEV_893` and `remotes/origin/GRNDEV_893`.

Git 2.23 (Q2 2019) will improve the code to show args with potential typo that *cannot* be interpreted as a commit-ish.

See [commit 2ed2e19](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2ed2e19958f2bcf59cac18a69b27f74ba7079a2f), [commit 8ed51b0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8ed51b066681adc88723dbe07b878904c348fdf6) (14 May 2019) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 8d32d25](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8d32d2552ee476917d216ae584d3d9b9002844d3), 13 Jun 2019)</sup>

> ### `help_unknown_ref()`: check for refname ambiguity
>
> When the user asks to merge "`foo`" and we suggest "`origin/foo`" instead, we do so by simply chopping off "`refs/remotes/`" from the front of the suggested ref.
>
> This is usually fine, but it's possible that the resulting name is ambiguous (e.g., you have "`refs/heads/origin/foo`", too).
>
> Let's use `shorten_unambiguous_ref()` to do this the right way, which
>   should usually yield the same "`origin/foo`", but "`remotes/origin/foo`" if
>   necessary.
>
> Note that in this situation there may be other options (e.g., we could suggest "`heads/origin/foo`" as well). I'll leave that up for debate; the focus here is just to avoid giving advice that does not actually do what we expect.

---

With Git 2.24, calling `help_unknown_ref()` exits the program.

See [commit 80e3658](https://github.com/git/git/commit/80e3658647561c4a8587978747752f6f63a96717) (29 Aug 2019) by [René Scharfe (`rscharfe`)](https://github.com/rscharfe).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 8e111e4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8e111e487bbb939406655619e7ed241bd263d85c), 30 Sep 2019)</sup>